# Perl: Net::Appliance::Session ssh connection gives weird characters on the output

Tags: perl, ssh

I'm using perl 5.8.8 with Net::Appliance::Session 1.36 and vim as editor.
On dev environment when I connect to the linux based network box and send commands with catching the output I get weird characters here and there plus doubled prompt:

```
Cisco Mobility Service Engine

root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
Last login: Thu May 17 14:19:01 from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx^M
^[]0;root@HOSTNAME:~^G^[[?1034h[root@HOSTNAME ~]# #no-paging-command^M
^[]0;root@HOSTNAME:~^G[root@HOSTNAME ~]#  $TIMESTAMP$=1526592421 ^Gecho no-paging-command^M
no-paging-command^M
^[]0;root@HOSTNAME:~^G[root@HOSTNAME ~]# ^G^M
^[]0;root@HOSTNAME:~^G[root@HOSTNAME ~]#  $TIMESTAMP$=1526592421 ^Ggetserverinfo^M
```

the strange characters I wrote about are:

```
^[]0;
```

This issue looks better on test and production environments:

```
Cisco Mobility Service Engine

root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
Last login: Tue May 15 10:59:10 from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx^M
[root@HOSTNAME ~]# #no-paging-command^M
[root@HOSTNAME ~]#  $TIMESTAMP$=1526517216 ^Gecho no-paging-command^M
no-paging-command^M
[root@HOSTNAME ~]# ^G^M
[root@HOSTNAME ~]#  $TIMESTAMP$=1526517216 ^Ggetserverinfo^M
```

What could be a root cause of different output in this case?

Thank you in advice!

Comment: You haven't specified which characters you consider weird.  If it's the bits like `^[[?1034h` those are ANSI escape sequences to do things like change the text color, alter the the cursor position, and place text in the terminal window titlebar.  Those sequences are typically set via environment variables like `PS1` in both the system and user profile scripts (`/etc/profile`, `~/.bashrc` etc). You could execute the command `PS1='$ '` to reduce the volume of these characters, but other variables and shell functions might need to be reset too.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have edited the question which characters I'm thinking about, but anyway you were right about the root cause.

Comment: One thing you might want to try is setting `TERM="dumb"` in your environment (`$ENV{TERM} = 'dumb'` in a Perl script). I'm guessing it's currently set to something like `xterm` or `vt100`.  This variable is usually propagated across an SSH connection and the `dumb` setting tells the remote end that your terminal doesn't understand escape sequences, so typically they will not be sent.

Answer (score -1):

You were right about those strange characters, those are ASCI chars that are setting additional terminal features which are very annoying for perl script to parse.
The way I got rid of them was to use the crontab the same way scripts are being run on production.